# How to watch a file and execute multiple commands when changed

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting, command

I need this in a python environment. Example [here on my Github](https://github.com/Createdd/data_science_boilerplate)

I have a file, `requirements.in`, and I want to watch if it changes. I add libraries to it and after saving it shall run a compile and install script.

I use `pip-compile` to compile the requirements into a `requirements.text` file. And then install with pip everything from this requirements file. Ideally I want to create a bundle script that also runs jupyter notebook.

Currently I used the python library "when-changed" and have this approach:

```sh
#!/bin/bash


jupyter notebook &
when-changed requirements_dev.in pip-compile requirements_dev.in && requirements_dev.in pip install -r requirements_dev.txt && echo 'Installed requirements'
```

The problem with this approach is that **it does only compile the requirements but not install it** or executes the echo statement. I guess this is due to the `when-changed`library that only can execute one command.

Therefore my question is: How can I watch the file and execute multiple commands? (Doesn't has to be a bash script. Can also be python or whatever suits best)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I came up with is to start the jupyter notebook in a separate terminal window and the watcher in another. The startup script then looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

pip-compile requirements_dev.in && pip install -r requirements_dev.txt && echo 'Installed requirements'
```

and I simply run

```sh
when-changed requirements_dev.in bash startup.sh
```

in an own window.

I would be open and curious for other solutions though.